# Division results in no data when using the 'and" operator

Tags: prometheus

I am e newbie with prometheus, I'll try to explain my problem clearly.

The 2 following queries return data in Promotheus

```
node_memory_MemAvailable{instance="10.0.0.15:9100",job="node-exporter"}

node_memory_MemTotal{instance="10.0.0.15:9100",job="node-exporter"}
```

And then I can divide them:

```
node_memory_MemAvailable{instance="10.0.0.15:9100",job="node-exporter"}/ node_memory_MemTotal{instance="10.0.0.15:9100",job="node-exporter"}
```

This is ok, so far.

I also have a query that gives me info about nodes:

```
node_meta
```

which returns:

```
...
node_meta{container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id="zekal76kw15vnp9u6ol0r2yvw",instance="10.0.0.15:9100",job="node-exporter",node_id="zekal76kw15vnp9u6ol0r2yvw",node_name="dc0-docker6"}
...
```

So, I can use the "and" operator in the 2 first queries to get the metric for a specific 'node_name':

```
node_memory_MemAvailable and on (instance) node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"}
```

and

```
 node_memory_MemTotal and on (instance) node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"}
```

These queries also returns data.

The problem is when I use the "/" operator:

```
node_memory_MemAvailable and on (instance) node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"} /node_memory_MemTotal and on (instance) node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"}
```

This result in a "no data" response and I don"t understand why. Anyone can help? How can I investigate this further?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` has a higher precedence than `and`, so try:

```
  (
      node_memory_MemAvailable 
    and on (instance) 
      node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"}
  )
/
  (
      node_memory_MemTotal 
    and on (instance)
      node_meta{node_name="dc0-docker6"}
  )
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much Brian.